# Создание приложения и обращение к нему через консоль с++

Tags: c++

Как создать приложение (на c++), которое можно запустить из обычной консоли, передав какие-нибудь параметры на основе которых оно будет что-то делать (Как реализовать сам доступ к приложению, что нужно сделать чтобы потом иметь возможность достучаться к нему по имени, как к примеру `nmp` в `node.js`, и командой заставить что-то делать)?

Comment: Прочтите об аргументах функции `main`...

Comment: @Harry да признаю, я плохо понимаю эти аргументы (обязательно прочту), но я имел ввиду немного другое: как мне обратиться к проге, каким образом это сделать, ну и как изнутри связать(хотя это уже то, что вы предложили).

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое [`PATH`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F))?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так под винду в среде студии:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    
int  main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            cout << argv[i] << endl;
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "chto to delaet") == 0)
            {
                cout << "chto to vivodit" << endl;
            }
            else if (strcmp(argv[i], "1") == 0)
            {
                cout << "11111111111111111111" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Argymentov nety" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В консоли пишите название программы и аргументы через пробел, например:

```
test.exe "chto to delaet" 1
```